# How to avoid hard coding data objects

Tags: vuejs3

The error I got was

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2021' of undefined

Data is obtained from an axios request:

```
created() {     
    axios
    .get('https://www.website.com')
    .then(response => (
        this.source = response.data
    ))        
    .catch(error => 
        console.log(error)
    )
},
```

I filter the data based on user input on previous form fields, via v-model on contact:

```
<option v-for="(item, index) in subjectsFilter(contact.year, contact.level)" :key="index" :value="index">
```

subjectsFilter:

```
  subjectsFilter(year, level){
      return this.source.subjects[year][level];
  }
```

If my data is defined as below, then I do not get this error:

```
data() {
  return {
      source: {subjects: {"2021": {}, "2022": {}, "2023": {}}}
  }
},
```

However the 2021, 2022, 2023 etc could be any years theoretically, so I would prefer not to have them hard coded.

Is there a way around hard coding these values?

Also, why must I define the year in the data object, but it seems I do not need to do the same for level?

Comment: **return** this.source.subjects?.[year]?.[level] || []

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Please answer question with this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**return** this.source.subjects?.[year]?.[level] || []